# Acsessing Radio Signals in the middle of Nowhere (North Wales)

Tags: technology

Hi I'm about to go to Wales, as a football fan I really would like to be able to listen the matches (especially when you are in the middle of nowhere). Is there a radio I can get (rather not do), or is there a hack or thing to do to get a much better Radio signal.

Comment: I hate to disappoint you but North Wales is not the middle of nowhere.  I have never had any difficulty getting radio reception of any kind at any location.  Also, why is this tagged "eyesight"?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing that will extend the range of a radio is a better antenna.

Note I said "better", which is not necessarily "bigger", though in almost all cases, a better antenna will be bigger than the ferrite core coils used in transistor radios in the 1970s.  Commonly a dipole fairly well matched to the broadcast wavelength and oriented for strongest reception is the best "easy" antenna -- but connecting it to the signal input of your receiver may be problematic.

If you're talking about your car radio, there isn't a practical way to enhance the aerial provided by the car maker (at least that will work while you're actually driving).  If you're talking about a home stereo receiver, on the other hand, there's likely an antenna with it that can be oriented for optimum reception -- and you can, if needed, improvise an antenna and connect it to the antenna terminal on the back of the unit.  In the US, you can even use an old "fishbone" television antenna for FM radio, as they're in the same frequency band (I don't know what bands UK radio and television use, so can't say if that would work there).

I can't tell you what dimensions your aerial will need, however; that would be fodder for another SE (ham radio, electronics, or similar).

Answer (score 1):

yes. There is (or was) a product called an antenna booster you could buy to enhance medium-wave reception. It consists of a flat plastic rectangle you set the radio on top of. a wire leads away from the rectangle; you stretch this out the window or through the attic in your house. Inside the plastic rectangle is a coil of wire that couples itself to the antenna coil inside your radio, which allows the signal picked up by the long wire to be fed into the radio without having to attach any wires to it.

Some of these boosters also have a tuning knob on them so the response of the booster can be matched to the station your radio is tuned in to. This allows the booster to reject strong signals elsewhere in the MW band, which might otherwise "leak" into your radio along with the weaker signal you want.

Answer (score 0):

The entire UK has very good free broadcast TV coverage. I suspect many would cover sports events.

Check-out the following, (among many) website for some background of what's available.

http://www.a516digital.com/p/freeview-channels-wales.html